# Which Eclipse for Android only?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am starting Android development. Which of the many Eclipse downloads do I need from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ ?

I am only ever going to do Android dev with Eclipse ever.

Platform: MAC 64 bit Snowleopard

Comment: ahmm.. if you just want the eclipse instance for android development, then, why exactly eclipse at all ? 
I mean, what do you usually use for development ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the SDK requirements page:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

On my Mac I am using the "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers".

Answer (score 2):

You either use Java developer or Jave EE, I am using the Java EE version
and then follwing the guide on developer.android.com to how setting up eclipse and adt

Answer (score 1):

*Eclipse IDE for Java Developers*  should be sufficient